# How to configure Monolog to send errors via SwiftMailer to alternate mailer in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, monolog

In my symfony2 application I have two mailers, and I'd like to use the non-default mailer to send monolog errors. Errors are being sent as expected now, but I can't get it to send to the non default mailer.

Here's my Swift Mailer configuration, in which I'd like to send errors using the "phpmail" mailer:

## Swiftmailer Configuration

```
default_mailer: authsmtp

mailers:
    authsmtp:
        transport: %mailer_transport%
        host:      %mailer_host%
        username:  %mailer_user%
        password:  %mailer_password%
        port:      %mailer_port%
        spool:     { type: memory }

    phpmail:
        transport: smtp
        host:      127.0.0.1
        spool:     { type: memory }
```

## And the relevant part of my Monolog configuration:

```
handlers:

    mail_on_errors:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: critical
        handler: buffered

    buffered:
        type:    buffer
        handler: swift

    swift:
        type:       swift_mailer
        mailer:     swiftmailer.mailer.phpmail
        from_email: %from_email_address%
        to_email:   [ %errors_receiving_address% ]
        subject:    An Error Occurred!
        level:      debug
```

You can see I tried to get this to work by adding "mailer: swiftmailer.mailer.phpmail" to the swift monolog handler----this isn't covered in the docs (that i can find anyway) so I just made this up, and it doesn't error out, but it also doesn't use the phpmail handler.

If anyone knows the proper configuration to get this to work I'd appreciate it!

Comment: In the Monolog configuration you've set `handlers.swift.mailer` to `swiftmailer.mailer.phpmail`, but it shoud be `swiftmailer.mailers.phpmail` (note the 's' at the end of 'mailers'), no?

Answer (score 0):

If you looked into the source code of *[\Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\MonologExtension](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php#L422)*, you find there all monolog definitions.

swift_mailer handler allows you to define a custom mailer by setting "mailer" key (as you guessed).

```
$messageFactory->setArguments(array(
    new Reference($handler['mailer']),
    $handler['from_email'],
    $handler['to_email'],
    $handler['subject'],
    $handler['content_type']
));
```

Are you sure that your phpmail is working correctly?