# Email critical errors using SendinBlue with Symfony monolog

Tags: symfony, monolog, sendinblue

I'm using this API to send emails in my application :
https://github.com/mailin-api/sendinblue-api-bundle

I would like to send an email to myself every time a critical error occurs.
I checked on this page : http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_email.html

But I couldn't figure out how to send my emails without swift.

**edit:**
I have to edit my question to tell that an answer about how to log into a database is not responding to my question about how to send an email through a specific api.
Well, it doesn't.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate (but it is not mark as resolved) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461962/how-to-configure-monolog-to-send-errors-via-swiftmailer-to-alternate-mailer-in-s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Monolog to store logs into MongoDB with Symfony2 and Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129162/how-to-configure-monolog-to-store-logs-into-mongodb-with-symfony2-and-doctrine)

Comment: Show us your monolog configuration.

Comment: There is an open ticket for this feature https://github.com/mailin-api/sendinblue-api-bundle/issues/8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom monolog handler for default monolog in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935979/custom-monolog-handler-for-default-monolog-in-symfony-2)

Comment: You would need to create a custom monolog handler service to use with SendInBlue for the desired error level.